# Why is this v-for not rendering properly and Am I returning it properly in the template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'm quite new to Vuejs, just created a fake dataset with json. The file contains an array of 3 objects. When I check on console.log I could understand that the Axios.get(URL) is fetching the data properly, but the v-for seems to have no effect and I'm not able to understanding why it is happening.

Here's the code (Parent Component):

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <EventCard v-for="event in events" :key="event.id" :event="event" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventCard from "@/components/EventCard.vue";
import axios from "axios";
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "EventList",
  components: {
    EventCard,
  },
  setup() {
    let events = [];

    onBeforeMount(async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Tommydemian/real-world-vue-3/db"
      );
      const { data } = res;
      events = data.events;
      console.log(events);
    });

    return {
      events,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

console.log:
[image]

code (Child Component) which receives the prop:

```html
<template>
  <div class="event-card">
    <span>@{{ event.time }} on {{ event.date }}</span>
    <h4>{{ event.title }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "EventCard",
  props: {
    event: Object,
  },
  setup() {
    console.log();
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`events` needs to be a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) or [`reactive`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) for it to be reactive in the template:

```js
// EventList.vue         
import { onBeforeMount, ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'EventList',
  components: {
    EventCard,
  },
  setup() {       
    let events = ref([])

    onBeforeMount(async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Tommydemian/real-world-vue-3/db')
      const { data } = res
              
      events.value = data.events
      console.log(events.value)
    })

    return {
      events,
    }
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-render-async-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FEventList.vue)

Answer (score 1):

on your console events has another object called events you need to assign data to `res.events` to access the main array of objects

you are passing events instead of event

````js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <EventCard v-for="event in events" :key="event.id" :event="event" />
  </div>
</template> ```
````

Comment: i changed it but still not working, very strange tho. Did both things, changed events for event and did this too: const { data } = res;
      events = data.events;

Comment: try cosole.log(res)  see the format of your response. you also can check data type it may be array then you need to `res[0].events`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass `event` as props in EventCard and not `events`. Since `events` is the collection of data. It has to be looped again once taken into the child component as props.  Since you are looping events in the parent component. It is better to pass only the `event` through props.

```
<EventCard v-for="event in events" :key="event.id" :event="event" />
```